# Unknown File Encoding in Mysqlworkbench 5.7.34

Tags: mysql, workbench

Mysql : 5.7,
workbench : 5.7.34

I want to import sql dump file, Problem is :

```
Unknown File Encoding

The file '/xxx.sql' is not UTF-8 encoded.

Please select the encoding of the file and press OK for Workbench to convert and open it.
Note that as Workbench works with UTF-8 text, if you save back to the original file,
its contents will be replaced with the converted data.

WARNING: If your file contains binary data, it may become corrupted.

Click "Run SQL Script..." to execute the file without opening for editing.

Character Set Encoding Name: latin1
```

img : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvXcG.png).
After importing with this *latin1* encoding, site content will change to wrong encoding format. sample : ă‚¤ăƒ™ăƒłăƒˆăƒťäźšč­°ăƒŹăƒăƒźă.

How to import dump file without encoding alert?

Comment: I would assume that you should not ignore that error, but fix the encoding

Comment: Please provide the hex of several bytes of the text in the source file -- without involving MySQL or Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Choose option "utf8". This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

thanks to my senior.
I fix it.

> Importing Process : in workbench, Server > Data Import > Import from
> Selt-Contained File. choose export sql dump file. And then choose
> Target db name. OK, that is all.

Error Importing Process : double-click sql dump file, workbench will auto open, Unknown Encoding Alert will occurs.

Answer (score -1):

select "ucs2" then run script/click button "ok".